# Error while importing miniworld in python over cluster

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I'm working on an RL project and testing my idea in MiniWorld [link](https://github.com/Farama-Foundation/Miniworld#usage) environment. I'm running my code in a cluster where there is no display. So I'm getting an error while importing the MiniWorld library
[image]
Is there any solution to this problem? I really appreciate any help you can provide. There might be a solution by port forwarding, but I'm not sure. I'm looking for a simple solution.

Comment: Are you connecting via ssh?  Are you on Linux?  You can use the `-X` parameter in ssh to do "X forwarding", which lets the remote system create windows on your system.